# Push to Heroku being rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I have created a simple site built on RoR. I've created a Git repository and have tried to deploy to Heroku but it keeps failing:

```
    remote:        rake aborted!
    remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected character '#' (line: 10848, col: 0, pos: 303135)
    remote:        Error
    remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20151027-1005-1i4h7l5js:2359:10623)
    remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs20151027-1005-1i4h7l5js:2359:10842)
```

(made a break in the errors for brevity)

```
    remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
    remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
    remote:  !
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy....
    remote:
    remote: !   Push rejected to serene-depths-4806.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/serene-depths-4806.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/serene-depths-4806.git'
```

Is it saying that there is a '#' that shouldn't be there? I'm not sure how to find that even though the line is given.

Also, I had changed from sqlite to postgresql and made the changes in the gemfile and database.yml file. I then deleted the old Heroku remote branch and followed these instructions to try and deploy: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, of course after writing that post, I found the answer (for those who might have the same issue in the future):

It's because the '#' error was in a .js file I had converted from the automated coffeescript files. Doh!  I just deleted the commentary at the top of the file and it deployed.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of assets precompilation failed and prevents the heroku deployment process.

You can try compiling assets locally to inspect the the error

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
```